# How do I route my button to another page using react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, navigation, react-router-dom

I have a Nutrition facts button on my page that  when clicked can route to another page on my site that lists the nutrition facts.  How do I make this happen?

Comment: Wrap your button component inside a Link component from react-router-dom

Answer (score 1):

- Basically you need to use `react-router-dom` package and make use of `BrowserRouter` and `Route` and `Switch` and define your routes.
- Then you need wrap your button with `Link` and indicate where to route to.

**Your app component**

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import NutritionPage from "./components/NutritionPage";
import NutritionFacts from "./components/NutritionFacts";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={NutritionPage}></Route>
          <Route path='/nutrition-facts' component={NutritionFacts}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**NutritionPage Component**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

const NutritionPage = (props) => {
    return (<div>
        <h2>My Nutrition Page</h2>
        <Link to='/nutrition-facts'><button>Nutrition Facts</button></Link>
    </div>)
};

export default NutritionPage;
```

NutritionFacts Component

```js
import React from 'react';

const NutritionFacts = (props) => {
    return (<div>Nutrition Facts List Page</div>)
};

export default NutritionFacts;
```

For more details and examples [read the docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and thorough response.

Comment: sure, anytime .. if it was helpful, you can consider to accept the answer..